# Как обратиться к переменной по имени?

Tags: javascript, переменные

Как правильно обратиться к переменной?

Допустим у меня есть:

```
var lalala_856 = "привет как дела?"
```

во время выполнения какого-то кода я получаю название этой переменной, но в виде строки `"lalala_856"` и соответственно `alert(lalala_856);` не работает.

Где то нашел следующее и оно работает, но правильно ли это:

`window[lalala_856]` или `eval(lalala_856)`.

Comment: `eval` - это очень плохо.

Comment: у меня ваш код работает без проблем

Comment: @Избытоксусликов автор и не говорил, что он не работает.

Comment: @Suvitruf      Да, уже читал, что eval это зло, пока плохо укладывается в голове, почему ?! Ну а если не eval то как ?

Comment: можно использовать условие, но зачем такое кодирование?